# Call back same method again under certain conditions

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have this object:

```
public class ObjectDisplay
{
    public int mMasterObjectID { get; set; }
    public ObjectInfo mMasterObject { get; set; }

    public int mChildObjectID { get; set; }
    public ObjectInfo mChildObject { get; set; }

    public ObjectDisplay()
    {
        mMasterObject = new ObjectInfo();

        mChildObject = new ObjectInfo();
    }
}
```

And `Object Display` is a class grouping a master object (the primary object which is always there) and a child object in the case that the `ObjectInfo.ObjectType` is not normal.

I have this method to fetch these items for me:

```
public Object GetObjectDisplayByID(int _objectID)
{
    Object objectToReturn = new Object();

    if (objectToReturn.mMasterObject == null)
    {
        return null;
    }

    if (objectToReturn.mMasterObject.ObjectType != "Normal")
    {
        if (objectToReturn.mMasterObject == null && objectToReturn.mChildObject == null)
        {
            mObjectDAL.LinkObjects();

            return GetObjectDisplayByID(objectToReturn.mMasterObject.mObjectID);
        }

        if (objectToReturn.mMasterObject.mMasterObjectID != null)
        {
            // If we are here then the primary object is in fact a child object.
            // We need to swap the objects and fetch the primary object which will become the child object.

            ObjectInfo child = objectToReturn.mMasterObject;

            objectToReturn.mMasterObject = mObjectDAL.GetObjectByID((int)child.mMasterObjectID);

            objectToReturn.mMasterObjectID = objectToReturn.mMasterObject.mObjectID;

            objectToReturn.mChildObject = child;
            objectToReturn.mChildObjectID = child.mObjectID;
        }
        else
        {
            if (objectToReturn.mMasterObject.mChildObjectID == null)
            {
                // The links are not made yet and we would need to redo them.
                mObjectDAL.LinkObjects();

                return mObjectDAL.GetObjectDisplayByID(objectToReturn.mMasterObject.mObjectID);
            }

            objectToReturn.mChildObject = mObjectDAL.GetObjectByID((int)objectToReturn.mMasterObject.mChildObjectID);
            objectToReturn.mChildObjectID = objectToReturn.mChildObject.mObjectID;
        }
    }

    return objectToReturn;
}
```

My main problem is that through these lines I have made it so that if there are no IDs yet, it means that the links are not made yet. I call an inner method to do the links:

```
if (objectToReturn.mMasterObject.mChildObjectID == null)
{
    // The links are not made yet and we would need to redo them.
    mObjectDAL.LinkObjects();

    return mObjectDAL.GetObjectDisplayByID(objectToReturn.mMasterObject.mObjectID);
}
```

What I want is to actually call the same method again, to "restart" the method. Am I doing it right? Is that what I actually called "recursively calling" the same method?

Comment: Yes, keep calling your method recursively (within the method) till the exit condition is met. See this for details http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)

Comment: Ok, so that means that it will make the links, then start the method once again? And I'm not creating a monster with my code?

Comment: not at all. At the point in your code where you want to call your method again. Place a condition that if satisfied you call your method again

Comment: All right, will try it out. Thanks!

Comment: i have posted it as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes You should call your method  [recursively](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_%28computer_science%29) If there is a condition in your code that if satisfied you want to do the same set of steps as defined in your method again unless the exit condition is met.